# Radix sort not sorting properly when given lots of numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I have to implement a Binary Radix sort for my assignment. While I have made it work, it stops properly sorting (doesn't actually sort them) once it hits a larger amount of numbers (usually 300+). Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
vector<unsigned char> A; //gets input from file that we have been given, containing 1000 numbers
vector<unsigned char> C(2);
vector<unsigned char> B(A.size());

for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
    B.push_back(0);
}

for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
    C[0] = 0;
    C[1] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        C[((int)A[i] >> k) & 1]++;
    }

    C[1] += C[0];

    for (int j = A.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        B[--C[(int)(A[j] >> k) & 1]] = (int)A[j];
    }

    std::swap(A, B);
}
```

After doing some testing, it seems that the limit is 256 numbers. So when it goes above 256 numbers, the algorithm can't sort it anymore

Comment: When you say it stops, what happens? Does it error? Just hang? Please clarify your question with details are too the problem

Comment: It actually doesn't sort them, you can find subgroups that are sorted but the whole sequence isn't. Whereas when I have less than 300 numbers, the whole sequence is perfectly sorted...

Comment: Your initial `B` array has too many elements in it, which can cause problems later.

Comment: not initializing it to all 0 / clearing it after every run, doesn't help so I don't think that's the problem...

Comment: after doing some testing, it seems that the limit is 256 numbers. So when it goes above 256 numbers, the algorithm can't sort it anymore

Comment: The first for-loop is odd. You already got B of size A.size() filled with zeros. After the loop you get B of size 2*A.size() filled with zeros.

Comment: Removing that for-loop or the argument from B doesn't solve the issue. Still seems to be stuck when there are more than 256 numbers...

Comment: C contains numbers 0..255, so it can't contain array indexes greater than 255.

Comment: Yes, why is your `vector` hold `char` types?  This is another case (many out there) where the comment in the code is a lie (you're getting numbers), but the code is the truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at declarations and usage

```
vector<unsigned char> C(2);
B[--C[(int)(A[j] >> k) & 1]]
```

Any element `C[i]` contains N between 0 and 255. Thus the index `--C[(int)(A[j] >> k) & 1]` is always less than 255.

Solution:

```
vector<size_t> C(2);
```